# jdbc getMetaData for a specific query

Tags: jdbc, clojure

In clojure/java jdbc, i have learned that using **getMetaData** i can return massive amounts of interesting information about a database connected to through jdbc. This can be filtered based on the catalog, schema, and table name.

```
(defn get-db-metadata 
    [db-spec ]
    (with-connection (get-db-connection-map db-spec)  
      ; get columns returs the following:
      ;  TABLE_CAT String       => table catalog (may be null)
      ;  TABLE_SCHEM String     => table schema (may be null)
      ;  TABLE_NAME String      => table name
      ;  COLUMN_NAME String     => column name
      ;  DATA_TYPE int          => SQL type from java.sql.Types
      ;  TYPE_NAME String       => Data source dependent type name, for a UDT the type name is fully qualified
      ;  COLUMN_SIZE int        => column size. For char or date types this is the maximum number of characters, for numeric or decimal types this is precision.
      ;  BUFFER_LENGTH          => not used.
      ;  DECIMAL_DIGITS int     => the number of fractional digits
      ;  NUM_PREC_RADIX int     => Radix (typically either 10 or 2)
      ;  NULLABLE int           => is NULL allowed.
      ;  columnNoNulls          => might not allow NULL values
      ;  columnNullable         => definitely allows NULL values
      ;  columnNullableUnknown  => nullability unknown
      ;  REMARKS String         => comment describing column (may be null)
      ;  COLUMN_DEF String      => default value (may be null)
      ;  SQL_DATA_TYPE int      => unused
      ;  SQL_DATETIME_SUB int   => unused
      ;  CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH int  => for char types the maximum number of bytes in the column
      ;  ORDINAL_POSITION int   => index of column in table (starting at 1)
      ;  IS_NULLABLE String     => "NO" means column definitely does not allow NULL values; "YES" means the column might allow NULL values. An empty string means nobody knows.
      ;  SCOPE_CATLOG String    => catalog of table that is the scope of a reference attribute (null if DATA_TYPE isn't REF)
      ;  SCOPE_SCHEMA String    => schema of table that is the scope of a reference attribute (null if the DATA_TYPE isn't REF)
      ;  SCOPE_TABLE String     => table name that this the scope of a reference attribure (null if the DATA_TYPE isn't REF)
      ;  SOURCE_DATA_TYPE short => source type of a distinct type or user-generated Ref type, SQL type from java.sql.Types (null if DATA_TYPE isn't DISTINCT or user-generated REF)
      (into #{}
            (map #(str (% :table_name) "." (% :column_name) "\n")
                 (resultset-seq (->
                                  (connection)
                                  (.getMetaData)
                                  ; Params in are catalog, schemapattern, tablenamepattern  
                                  ;(.getColumns "stuff" "public" nil "%")
                                  (.getColumns "db_catalog" "schema_name" "some_table" "%")
                                  )
                                )
                 )
            )
      )
    )
```

I'm interested in this information not for every table in the database, but rather for the result set returned by a *specific query*.  My needs specifically at this point for doing this is to know the max length of a particular column that is retrieved, to print to the screen for instance in fixed-width format.

**What i have considered so far (not ideal i'm sure):**

1. Trying to parse the in-bound sql statement to figure out what tables
   are being queried and then fetching the metadata for those tables
   specifically.  This would prove to be complicated with the results
   of a select statement with functions, or common table expressions, etc.
   I think it could get messy (and inaccurate) quickly.
2. What also may work would be to create a temporary view based on the
       inbound query... then i could fetch the metadata on this view.  This
       however wouldn't work if i only had a read-only connection to the
       database i was working with. often the case i believe for what i am trying to do.
3. Fetching the results, and then for each column returned finding the
       max length of the values, and then creating my fixed-width grid
       accordingly.  This wouldn't be great if i was looking at large
       result sets.....

Is there a better way to determine the types of everything i'm returning from my query?  How do other programs do this?  It seems like i should be able to get the metadata from the time i issue the query request somehow here:

```
(defn fetch-results 
  "Treat lazy result sets in whole for returning a database query"  
  [db-spec query] 
  (with-connection 
    (get-db-connection-map db-spec) 
    (with-query-results res query 
      ; (get the medata here somehow for columns returned ????)
      (doall res))
    )
  )
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know clojure, but can't you just use the [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) object returned by [`ResultSet.getMetaData()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData())

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm going to try to get this to work as it seems it's the appropraite option in regards to efficiency.  

FYI, in clojure i'm not quite sure how to do it yet as the ResultSet processing seems to be taken care of for me in with-query-results... i'll keep at it and post and answer in time (hopefully).

Comment: I have come across **print-table** that somewhat helps this.... although it's not a metadata approach and it doesn't print the columns out in order.  Keeping at it, although this helps some. 

    [link]http://richhickey.github.io/clojure/clojure.pprint-api.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in scala, may be this can help you out:

```
var stmt: PreparedStatement = null
var rs: ResultSetMetaData = null
try {
  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)
  rs = stmt.getMetaData()
} finally {
  cleanup(stmt)
}
}
```